# Display continent labels, then countries, then cities d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a d3 map. Currently I'm working on getting labels for my map. Basically, On the outer most zoom, it should show the continent names. As you zoom, countries should show up, then cities. I'm not sure exactly how you would go about doing this. Would you need a dataset with the long/lats of each label?

I'm aware that for countries, you can put the text at the centroid of its path, but i found that it didn't work very -- they were in weird positions. However, I don't have paths for continents, and cities, so I don't see how that could work for me regardless.

How should i go about this?

Comment: Map annotation (labels) is an incredible amount of work to do right at multiple zoom levels over wide areas. It is probably easiest to use a tile layer for [labels](http://maps.stamen.com/toner-labels/#2/16.0/65.0)/other things/everything, and overlay your information on/under that. You'll not be able to modify the lablels, but the most accessible alternative method is to place the labels manually for each zoom level.

Comment: Do you know of any datasets with the longitude/latitude positions for all the labels?

Comment: No. Any such file would need to be projection and language (and somewhat font) specific to ensure proper placement and to avoid overlap. You could try finding an annotation file for use in GIS software and exporting that as a csv for each zoom level if you have access to ArcMap or something. Leaflet may offer some annotation options for label placement (in plug ins). Ultimately, map annotation is not fun.